# C# Linq check existing values

Tags: c#, linq

In the following sample of code I am storing in a var, a list with a specific email in the payload:

```
var emailList = new List<string> {payload.Email};
```

Next, I create a var, in which I am returning a list of tha existing emails  that there are in the database so far:

```
var allRegisteredUsersEmailAdresses = new List<string>();
```

In which way(Linq) can I compare if the second variable includes the first one? For example if the given mail exists in the second listing, set a var valuefound=true else var valuefound=false

Thank you

Comment: Look at the `Contains` method.

Comment: @CraigW. IMO not so suitable here, it would be probably easier to use [except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx) or intersect.

Comment: @pasty `Except` or `Intersect` would be too costly here, if we only need to know if there is an intersection.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 IMO negligible - both are linear and you are looping twice - `Contains` in the `Any` . [Enumerable.Any](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0) vs. [Enumerable.Intersect](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ae06318d1f5fb355).

Comment: @pasty Actually, `Except` and `Intersect` is the same in term of complexity as `Any(Contains)`, as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,785) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,763). The real difference depends whether or not do you return as soon as a match is found. Therefore, `Intersect().Any()` and `Any(Contains)` should have the best performance.

Comment: @pasty You should also look into`set.Add()` and `set.Remove`.

Comment: You guys are micro-optimizing in an area that, in all likelihood, won't make a sniff of difference in the grand scheme of things. That leaves the question of which is more readable/understandable. While it's fun to show how smart a developer you are by using Intersect or Except, the Contains approach would be far easier to read/understand the intent by another developer coming into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally, if any of the registered users is contained in the email list :

```
allRegisteredUsersEmailAdresses.Any(registeredUser => emailList.Contains(registeredUser))
```

Comment: So, in "x" i have to place the value that I want to check for? Its is not clear in **my mind**

Comment: The `x` along with the `=>` is the lambda function, which is applied to every member of the registered users. You can see it as `registeredUser`, if that helps you understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for the response (I noticed that you modified to be more clear for me). Placed a breakepoint and got "Count=1" as a response, so I suppose that is 1 record found or 1=true 0=false(dummy question)?

Comment: @GeorgeD the result of this is a boolean, either true or false. You may have hovered your cursor over `allRegisteredUsersEmailAdresses` or `emailList`, and visual studio is telling you how many items are inside that list. Or... that second part is replying to @Love's answer. In that case, the count tells how many intersection you have found.

Answer (score 3):

Using intersect.

```
var intersect =first.Intersect(second).ToList();
```

if the count of `intersect` is 0, then `valuefound=false`

Comment: I am going to make an approach with this way

Comment: You don't have to create the list, access its `.Count()` and compare it to `0`. Simply `first.Intersect(second).Any()` should suffice.